# Sidekiq - custom job scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I need to implement custom scheduler for user.

Example scenario:
User sets exact job to be run on Monday at 12:00AM, then edits it to be performed on Fridays etc. All of that in GUI interface.

How to do it with sidekiq? I know there is sidekiq scheduler but it's based on predefined .yml config file.

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3702#issuecomment-353358576

Answer (score 0):

use cron jobs. https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron. save user jobs in the database and invoke jobs.

```
Sidekiq::Cron::Job.new(name: 'some database id', cron: '*/5 * * * *', class: 'HardWorker')
```

when the user deletes or changes the job just search the job and destroy. then create a new one.

```
Sidekiq::Cron::Job.find('some database id').destroy
```